# preg_replace value dynamically php

Tags: php

I want to change these links dynamically

from

```
mysite.com/some-link-here-t123.html
mysite.com/some-link-here-t456.html
mysite.com/some-link-here-t789.html
```

to

```
mysite.com/some-link-here-tid123.html
mysite.com/some-link-here-tid456.html
mysite.com/some-link-here-tid789.html
```

I tried using below

```
<?php 
$string2 = preg_replace('/-t([^0-9.html]*)/','-tid$1',$string);
?>
```

but its messing up all the other words starts from `-t` like `-table` becomes `-tidable`
how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `.html` inside the character group? And why do you negate the group with `^` at the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to limit your regex to only match numbers after the '-t' Like so:

```
<?php 
$string2 = preg_replace('/-t([0-9]+)/','-tid$1',$string);
?>
```

Comment: /-t([0-9]+)\.html/ just in case they have a URL like mysite.com/some-link-here-t90-t123.html